# Cual es la forma correcta de agregar código SQL en las respuestas?

Tags: soporte

He agregado código **SQL-SERVER** en una respuesta pero no he visto que se marque las palabras clave como ejemplo *SELECT*, *FROM*, *UPDATE* con diferente color. 
Para agrear el código he usado la etiqueta **Texto con formato previo**, cual es la mejor forma para agregar fragmentos de codigo SQL o  tienes que darle un formato al código antes de agregarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza la etiqueta `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` para forzar el marcado del código como SQL:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    SELECT *
    FROM tabla
```

El código lucirá así (fragmento SQL con palabras claves resaltadas):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tabla
```

Para más detalles, revisa la [Ayuda de edición de Markdown, Resaltado de sintaxis para código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), específicamente esta parte:

> Puedes utilizar [uno de los códigos compatibles de lenguaje prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), como lang-cpp o lang-sql, o puedes especificar una etiqueta y se utilizará el lenguaje de resaltado de sintaxis relacionado con [ella].

Comment: Adicionalmente aclaro que hay que luego al inicio de cada línea de código hay que poner 4 espacios o un tabulador (` `).

Comment: Acabo de descubrir un bug. Mariano había puesto la imagen porque decía que en Meta no había Markdown, pero sí que hay. Si miro el historial de ediciones de esta respuesta, en la edición 2 no aparece el con colores, pero si toco en **insertada** aparece con colores en la edición 2 y en todas las demás ediciones, y luego vuelvo a **en paralelo** entonces siguen estando los colores.