# En el historial de ediciones hay resaltado de sintaxis solo al cambiar de "insertada" a "en paralelo" y viceversa

Tags: bug, formato, revisiones, resaltado-de-sintaxis

Acabo de editar una respuesta aquí en *Meta* sobre el Markown de SQL.

- Pregunta: [Cual es la forma correcta de agregar código SQL en las respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/969)
- Respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/970

Vi un poco desordenada la respuesta y decidí editarla. En la respuesta, en vez del código había una captura de pantalla y la quité cambiando por el código.

Además dejé un comentario.

> *Adicionalmente aclaro que hay que luego al inicio de cada línea de código hay que poner 4 espacios o un tabulador ().  – [ArtEze](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze) [hace x tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/969/cual-es-la-forma-correcta-de-agregar-c%c3%b3digo-sql-en-las-respuestas/970#comment18972_970)*

Al ver el historial de ediciones vi que Mariano cambió el código por la imagen. Pongo el comentario de Mariano en la edición 3.

> No hay resaltado en meta. Puse una imagen

y además noté un bug. Entonces dejé otro comentario.

> *Acabo de descubrir un bug. Mariano había puesto la imagen porque decía que en Meta no había Markdown, pero sí que hay. Si miro el historial de ediciones de esta respuesta, en la edición 2 no aparece el con colores, pero si toco en **insertada** aparece con colores en la edición 2 y en todas las demás ediciones, y luego vuelvo a **en paralelo** entonces siguen estando los colores. – [ArtEze](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze) [hace x tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/969/cual-es-la-forma-correcta-de-agregar-c%c3%b3digo-sql-en-las-respuestas/970#comment18973_970)*

La cuestión es que sin la etiqueta `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` se ve sin colores:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
```

Con la etiqueta se ve con colores:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tabla
```

En la edición 1, se ve que había algo extraño que hacía que no se vean los colores:

```
Utiliza la etiqueta `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` para forzar el marcado del código como SQL:

> `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`
>     
>     SELECT *
>     FROM tabla

El código lucirá así:

<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    SELECT *
    FROM tabla
```

En verdad no sé la causa de por qué esa edición la muestra sin colores. Noté que al eliminar un salto de línea (no recuerdo si era exactamente este).

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
    SELECT *
```

y volver a ponerlo, entonces muestra los colores.

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    SELECT *
```

Pensé que había un caracter extraño, pero con un editor hexadecimal comprobé que no había nada raro. Es que al cambiar algo en el *textarea* se activan los colores.

La primera vez que se muestren los colores, se mostrarán siempre y en todos lados, pero mientras no haya ningún color que mostrar, al final no se mostrarán.

Además, como indiqué en el comentario, al ver el historial de ediciones, en la edición 1 y 2, antes de que la haya editado Mariano, no se muestran los colores, pero al cambiar de **insertada** a **en paralelo**  muestra los colores, y al volver a **insertada** sigue mostrando los colores.

Lo raro es que en el historial de ediciones muestra los colores en mi edición, pero no en 1 y 2, y al clickear esos botones, se muestra los colores también en esas dos primeras.

---

Quise ver si pasaba esto en otros sitios de *StackExchange*, y veo que también sucede, por ejemplo, en una pregunta en *StackOverflow en inglés*.

La pregunta es la siguiente:

[Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array)

La edición 29 está en la página 3 actualmente, aunque en el futuro puede quedar en una página mayor.

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/revisions?page=3#

Muestro unas capturas de pantalla. En principio, está en **side-by-side** y se muestra sin colores.

[image: side by side]

Luego se cambia a **inline**:

[image: inline]

Finalmente se ven los colores del código.

Además, si toco en la flechita para cerrar y abrir la revisión, se mantiene los colores por unas centésimas de segundo y se vuelve a poner sin colores.

Comment: Interesante descubimiento. Navegué un rato por Meta.SE y no encontré ningún reporte similar ni tampoco está explicado en [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/83)